# How do I connect a Macbook early 2011 to a Sony trv 340 via Firewire

Tags: macbook-pro, firewire

I have a Sony trv 340, and need to firewire from the cam to my Macbook, but have no idea what is need for the Mac. Do I need a male end or a female to go to the laptop? I have no idea what I’m looking at, and don't even know how to start searching.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/camcorders-tape-camcorders/dcr-trv340/articles/S1F0064 . See if this helps. The link in “ilink” talks well about connections and also refers to an apple support article.

Comment: Thank you both very much @nohillside and gummibando great info great answers. Thank you for taking the time out of your day to help. Thank you. ✌️✌️✌️✌️✊✊

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your machine is indeed a MacBook **Pro** 2011, you need a Firewire 800 (9-pin) to MiniDV (4-pin Firewire or i.Link in Sony speak) cable. Something like this:

[https://www.amazon.com/FireWire-i-link-IEEE-1394-Cable-Clear/dp/B002RB84P8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002RB84P8)

[https://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-FireWire-Hi-speed-F019-006/dp/B000AAZQM2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000AAZQM2)

Comment: Thank you @gummibando for taking the time out to help. Thank you very very much. ✊❤️